# Существует ли в Visual Studio комбинация клавиш для сдвига выделенных строк?

Tags: visual-studio

Существует ли в Visual Studio комбинация клавиш для сдвига выделенных строк? Т.е. выделенные строки сдвигаются на табулятор влево или вправо.

Как например в Delphi 7  Ctrl+Shift+U - сдвиг влево и Ctrl+Shift+I - сдвиг вправо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вправо: Tab, влево: Shift + Tab

Comment: Спасибо, просто привык  уже в Delphi этим пользоваться)) А в Visual Studio все время мучался, когда возникала такая необходимость.